# Dummy code interaction among categorical variables

Tags: spss, interaction, categorical-encoding

Do you know if there is a way of dummy coding the interactions among three independent categorical variables using SPSS? (with two levels each)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need dummy coding here. An interaction is the product between variables (see [here](https://stattrek.com/multiple-regression/interaction.aspx) for example). Since all of your variables are binary (0 or 1), the product will also be binary. Consider the following example of a three-way interaction between three binary variables V1, V2 and V3:

```
V1  V2  V3    IA-3 (V1*V2*V3)
0   0   0     0
0   0   1     0
0   1   0     0
0   1   1     0
1   0   0     0
1   0   1     0
1   1   0     0
1   1   1     1
```

As you can see, the three-way interaction IA-3 is binary, hence you do not need dummy coding here. So all you need is to calculate products. For the example above it would be

```
COMPUTE IA_3=V1 * V2 * V3.
EXECUTE.
```